# regular expression remove words within string python

Tags: python, regex

how do I remove the word `a` in this string?

`We are at a boat sale near a dock.`

result

`We are at boat sale near dock.`

I've tried:

`removed = original.replace(" a", "")` , 
`removed = original.replace(" a ", "")`

Comment: What is your problem with the second trial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just needed to replace with a space.

```
'We are at a boat sale near a dock.'.replace(" a ", " ")
# Result: We are at boat sale near dock. #
```

I'm not sure what other strings you are trying to do this with but if you can get away with it try to use string ops like this instead of `regex` for better performance.

Comment: I didn't get to post an answer, so instead I'll just provide a [link to a demo](https://repl.it/BPuR) :)

Comment: @Green Cell, this doesn't work for `a We are at a boat sale near a dock.`

Comment: `replace("a ", "")` would work. (and yes I know this would fail if `a` was at the end)
He asked for a specific string, so I gave him an answer for that specific string.

Comment: @GreenCell, what about a general solution?

Comment: Here's a general solution: `'a We are at a boat sale near a dock. a'.replace(' a ', ' ').lstrip('a ').rstrip(' a')`

Awaiting your answer too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try by this way using regexp

```
 import re
 s= "We are at a boat sale near a dock."
 op = re.sub(r'\ba\b\s+',"",s)
 op
```

In python console

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'We are at a boat sale near a dock.'
>>> op = re.sub(r'\ba\b\s+',"",s)
>>> op
'We are at boat sale near dock.'
```

Comment: That isn't the output OP asked for (extra spaces)

Comment: Now it's getting double spaces. Are you checking your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps.

```
word_a = re.compile(r'\ba\b')
spaces = re.compile(r'\s+')
spaces.sub(' ', word_a.sub('', 'We are at a boat sale near a dock'))
```

`\b` matches beginning or end of a word, but that alone will give us continuous spaces, so we replace multiple spaces `\s+` with one space.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:
1. Using `replace`

```
>>> line = """ We are at a boat sale near a dock. """
>>> line.replace(" a "," ")
' We are at boat sale near dock. '
```

2. Using regular expression and replace double space by single space:

   (re.sub(r'\ba\b','',line)).replace("  "," ")